# Effect of Cropping Black Parts - Data Augmentation

Tags: database-design, machine-learning, computer-vision

I was trying to apply different data augmentation strategies for an image classification problem. When I apply things like rotation, it results in some black margins. Is these black margins detrimental to our CNN network? The fact that it is shown the first conv layer is sensitive to gabor like filters makes me wonder that it only cares about edges, but to a normal eye it is better that although the edge has remained, the color becomes more similar to the color of the background. Should I crop out these black regions?

Answer (score 1):

It's common to keep black pixels when augmenting a dataset. For example, we might pad a 32x32x3 image with four pixels on each side and take a random crop of that image. The resulting image will likely have a few black pixels. Also, when performing the convolution operation your library might automatically add black pixels to your image. Adding black pixels is ubiquitous and not detrimental.

Comment: Thanks, now is it bad to fill them with a color similar to background?